# Multidimensional Array rearrange by DESC order , internal Multidimensional array is in DESC but outer parent array not work

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Working child array is here with parent multidimensional array.Here
child array is run as in DESC order.

```
 [
    {
        "variation_id": "23",
        "variation_price": "200.00"
    },
    {
        "variation_id": "25",
        "variation_price": "100.00"
    }
],
[
    {
        "variation_id": "31",
        "variation_price": "150.00"
    },
    {
        "variation_id": "30",
        "variation_price": "80.00"
    }
],
[
    {
        "variation_id": "45",
        "variation_price": "300.00"
    },
    {
        "variation_id": "44",
        "variation_price": "200.56"
    }
]
```

And would like to work as  in order like , Thank means whole multidimensional ( parent and child array ) work in DESC order.

```
[
    [
        {
            "variation_id": "45",
            "variation_price": "300.00"
        },
        {
            "variation_id": "44",
            "variation_price": "200.56"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "variation_id": "23",
            "variation_price": "200.00"
        },
        {
            "variation_id": "25",
            "variation_price": "100.00"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "variation_id": "31",
            "variation_price": "150.00"
        },
        {
            "variation_id": "30",
            "variation_price": "80.00"
        }
    ]

]
```

I have written query for first to get child array as DESC order to get results for Query ->

```
$response  = $find_variation_array;
$sort = array();
foreach($response as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['variation_price'][$k] = $v['variation_price'];
}
array_multisort($sort['variation_price'], SORT_DESC, $response);
```

**Not working for second steps , which is parent array .**
Can any one kindly share me any idea how to get whole parent and child multidimensional  array in DESC order more. Thanks in advance for your kind knowledge share.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is like this:

```
[ 
    [
        [
            "variation_id" => "23",
            "variation_price" => "200.00"
        ],
        [
            "variation_id" => "25",
            "variation_price" => "100.00"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "variation_id" => "31",
            "variation_price" => "150.00"
        ],
        [
            "variation_id" => "30",
            "variation_price" => "80.00"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "variation_id" => "45",
            "variation_price" => "300.00"
        ],
        [
            "variation_id" => "44",
            "variation_price" => "200.56"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Then it may be an way to solve:

```
$test_array = 
[ 
    [
        [
            "variation_id" => "23",
            "variation_price" => "200.00"
        ],
        [
            "variation_id" => "25",
            "variation_price" => "100.00"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "variation_id" => "31",
            "variation_price" => "150.00"
        ],
        [
            "variation_id" => "30",
            "variation_price" => "80.00"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "variation_id" => "45",
            "variation_price" => "300.00"
        ],
        [
            "variation_id" => "44",
            "variation_price" => "200.56"
        ]
    ]
];


$sort_array_order = array();
foreach ($test_array as $test_key => $test_value) {

    $temp_sumation_of_variation_price = 0;

    foreach ($test_value as $key => $value) {
        $temp_sumation_of_variation_price += $value['variation_price'];
    }

    $sort_array_order[] = $temp_sumation_of_variation_price;
}

array_multisort($sort_array_order, SORT_DESC, $test_array);

echo "<pre>";print_r($test_array);echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: why I got the negative marking? Please, explain it.